# Displaying "Cannot find endtime" on Using hisorian.py

Tags: android, performance

I am trying to gather Battery stats for my app. 
After running all the commands specified on http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/batterystats-battery-historian/index.html

The txt file generated has the data of app battery. But using battery.py script to convert to HTML file. Opening Html file shows blank html page only containing the text
"Cannot find endtime" instead of piecharts.

Comment: can we see that script

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Even I have this issue yet, what could be the problem?? Is is device specific?

Comment: Am having the same problem. How do you overcomed it?

Comment: This is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487749/battery-historian-cannot-find-end-time-android/41262985#41262985).

Comment: @satheeshwaran yes it is device specific, see related discussion.